# 2 menus in different language points to same menu in main language

Tags: joomla, menu, multilingual

I've created 2 menus in joomla (login page in English and Lithuanian) then I visit login page in lithuanian it points to e.g lt/pages/loginas and in english language it points to en/pages/loginas, however I've created in english language link like /pages/loginasEN. So I want for english language the link /pages/loginasEN not /pages/loginas, the reason is that I have some custom settings in menu link, so in both languages I have the same text(lithuanian).

Comment: May be you should create aliases in different languages which will point to main language menu item?

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing in the last week.

You should have something like this:

Two articles in different languages, or one common article. Then you choose in menu the type (e.g. single article) and set the title of the first menu item to `loginasEN`, and the second to `loginas`.  Both are child of `pages` menu.

For each submenu you choose the article in the specific language (en/lt), or the same article (e.g in your case english) to both sub-menus of `pages`.

This is the common procedure. And it works perfectly. Joomfish is a great help.